# When do evaluation functors reflect (co)limits?

Tags: category-theory

It is a well known result that limits in functor categories are computed pointwise. In Tom Leinster's *Basic Category Theory* he phrases this result in terms of the evaluation functors $\mathrm{ev}_C:\mathsf{A^C}\times \mathsf C\rightarrow \mathsf A$:

> The evaluation functors preserve limits.

Here's the statement of the theorem:

[image]

> What about reflecting limits? When do the evaluation functors also reflect limits, and what is an example in which they don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Individual evaluation functors $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{A}] \to \mathcal{A}$ do not reflect limits. (Think about, say, terminal objects.) However:

> The evaluation functors $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{A}] \to \mathcal{A}$ *jointly* reflect limits, i.e. given any diagram $X : \mathcal{I} \to [\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{A}]$ and any cone $\lambda : \Delta A \Rightarrow X$ in $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{A}]$, if $\operatorname{ev}_c \lambda$ is a limiting cone in $\mathcal{A}$ for every object $c$ in $\mathcal{C}$, then $\lambda$ is a limiting cone in $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{A}]$.

This is something that you get "along the way" in the proof of the theorem you cite.

Comment: I don't see how we get this along the way yet. Also, it seems that this "computing pointwise" only gives us a formula value of the limit of $D$ on objects, not on arrows. What about the value of $\varinjlim D$ on arrows?

Comment: There's only one thing it can be.

Comment: Is the statement 'the evaluation functors joinly reflect limits' equivalent to the statement 'the "global" evaluation functor $\mathrm{ev}_\mathsf{AC}:\mathsf{A^C}\times \mathsf C\rightarrow \mathsf A$ reflects limits'? Here the "global evaluation functor" is the counit of the product-hom adjunction in $\mathsf{Cat}$.

Comment: No. Why are you thinking about that functor? You would end up having to think about limits in $\mathcal{C}$ as well.

Comment: I was just trying to understand whether these theorems might hold in more general cartesian closed categories.

Comment: I would suggest that you think hard about the primary example before trying to generalise.